# ERROR 1442: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have a table that I want : when the table has been updated, 2 fields of that (title and description) change and take value from another table

This is my trigger:

```
drop trigger trigger_trade_request ;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_trade_request AFTER UPDATE ON `trade_request` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

  IF NEW.title = null THEN

    UPDATE `trade_request_type`,`trade_request` 
       SET NEW.title = `trade_request_type`.title ,
           NEW.description = `trade_request_type`.description
     WHERE `trade_request_type`.id = NEW.trade_request_typeId;

  END IF;   
END;
```

My tables:

- trade_request_type
- trade_request

error:

> ERROR 1442 : Can't update table 'trade_request' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

It does not work! What is the prob?

Comment: What does" does not work" mean?  If you get a specific error, provide details.  That said, `IF NEW.title = null THEN` should be `IF NEW.title IS NULL THEN`

Comment: i has edited that, check it plz

Comment: Does mySQL have `INSTEAD OF` triggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `is null` to check for null values.
2. To change the value of the updated row use `BEFORE` trigger and `SET` on the `NEW` row.

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_request BEFORE UPDATE ON `trade_request`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.title IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.title = (SELECT title FROM trade_request_type
            WHERE trade_request_type.id = NEW.trade_request_typeId);
        SET NEW.description = (SELECT description FROM trade_request_type
            WHERE trade_request_type.id = NEW.trade_request_typeId);
    END IF;
END;
```

Probably you can use the `SELECT...INTO` syntax instead of `SET`, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_request BEFORE UPDATE ON `trade_request`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.title IS NULL THEN
        SELECT title, description
        FROM trade_request_type
        WHERE trade_request_type.id = NEW.trade_request_typeId
        INTO NEW.tile, NEW.description;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to update the other table too.
Try that:

```
UPDATE `trade_request`
   SET NEW.title = `trade_request_type`.title ,
       NEW.description = `trade_request_type`.description
 FROM `trade_request_type`
 WHERE `trade_request_type`.id = NEW.trade_request_typeId;
   AND `trade_request_type`.id = `trade_request`.id
```

Comment: i think this will also explode, because you're updating the table that's firing the trigger for being updated.